# How to install an elasticsearch cluster on azure with different subscriptions?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, nest

How to install an elasticsearch cluster on azure with different subscriptions?

I have a credit limitation on multiple subscriptions so I cannot create the machines on the same virtual network. By my understanding, connecting virtual networks would be too expensive.

So:

1) I cannot use the same virtual network. The nodes will be on different virtual networks, only accessible by the public IP.

3) The machines will be on the same datacenter (but different subscriptions).

4) The machines will be running Linux Ubuntu.

5) I will not be using the azure cloud services, just standard classic virtual machines (because the machines will be on different subscriptions).

6) I want it to be secure, with no external access to the elasticsearch nodes.

I've tried to understand this tutorial:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/cloud-azure-discovery-long.html

But it seems to depend on using cloud services. Am I right?

Also, how would I connect to the nodes, since I cannot use a load balancer? I am using Nest, so I guess it should be done on the client level?
http://nest.azurewebsites.net/elasticsearch-net/cluster-failover.html

Would It work if I use the public ips on the unicast discover and protect external access on the firewall level?

Thanks.